# Problems with wired network on acer aspire 1410

Tags: 11.10, networking, drivers, ethernet, pci

The problem is the following: i can't establish a wired connection on Acer Aspire 1410 with Ubuntu 11.10 installed. Wireless connection works fine. But when i plug the network cable and disable wifi nothing happens.
Here is my lspci

```
lspci -nn | grep Ethernet                                                                                               130
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications AR8131 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1063] (rev c0)
```

Here is ifconfig eth0

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:11:22:33:44:55  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:4293051801 errors:4283474320 dropped:4291136304 overruns:4293051800 frame:4294967295
      TX packets:4293051800 errors:4287305312 dropped:0 overruns:4293051800 carrier:4294967295
      collisions:4285389816 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:4293051800 (4.2 GB)  TX bytes:4293051800 (4.2 GB)
      Interrupt:46
```

I could't find any information on the internet. What is wrong with my wired connection. It seemed to work on earlier Ubuntu versions. How can i solve the problem?

`cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

no-auto-default=00:26:9e:59:63:2c,

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Comment: Have you tested the wired connection with any machine other than the Acer? Have you tried swapping out the Ethernet cable? Have you another OS on the Acer you can boot into and test the Ethernet? Have you any lights on the network interface card on the Acer when the cable is plugged in?

Comment: @user30275
I have both Windows an Ubuntu on this laptop. Everything is fine when i boot to Windows. The light near the interface is green. It turn on whenever i plug in the Ethernet cable.

Comment: What is the problem??? Is it a dhcp connection?? if it is try to run dhclient eth0??? if it is a static connection assign an ip address by running if config eth0 [ip address]

Comment: @Manula Waidyanatha
Yes, it's dhcp. dhclient eth0 hangs when run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is probably a problem with your network manager. can you give the output of both of these:

cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
cat /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: I've edited the post. See please

Comment: try changing the 
`managed=true`
and restart networking by

`sudo service networking stop`
`sudo service networking start`